# How to save PHP session after browse closing? (without separate cookies)

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, session-variables

There are a lot of Stack Overflow questions which advise using separate cookies to keep session parameters, but I don't want to store any additional cookies on the client side.

At the moment I have a new session with empty session parameters after each browser restart.

Is there any way to keep the PHP session active after each browser restart?

The site is very simple without a database. I'm storing all data in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you use session_start function to start a new session. If I am correct then you have default lifetime for PHPSESSID cookie with is equals to 0. Zero lifetime means that cookie is session cookies.

Session cookies are deleted when the current session ends. The browser defines when the "current session" ends, and almost all browses ends the session when the browse is closed.

You can try to set lifetime for session cookie with session_set_cookie_params function. The first input parameter is $lifetime which define lifetime of the session cookie, defined in seconds.

Just try to execute session_set_cookie_params(86400) before session_start and check if my answer is suitable for you.

Comment: Great. It works! I'm wondering why in other questions nobody wrote this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP session has a "cookie lifetime" parameter which can be set with [the `session.cookie_lifetime` ini setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) or [the `session_set_cookie_params` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

> Specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0.

So, by default, the browser will be told to persist the cookie only until it is closed, but setting this to anything other than zero will instead instruct the browser to delete the cookie at a specific time in the future.

For instance, a lifetime of 86400 means "when starting the session, calculate a date 24 hours (86400 seconds) in the future, and set that as the expiry date on the cookie sent to the browser".

Important notes:

- To have any effect, this setting needs to be set *before calling `session_start`*, since that's when PHP will generate the `Set-Cookie` header to send to the browser.
- There is a separate [`session.gc_maxlifetime` setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) which determines when to delete the data *on the server*. That should be set to a value at least as long as the cookie lifetime, otherwise a returning user may have a session ID cookie, but no session data on the server.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering why in other questions nobody wrote this approach? Could there be any unexpected issues?

Comment: @Anton_John That depends what other questions you're talking about, you didn't actually link to any.